# Device that connects to a switch via RJ45, that emulates a PC

Tags: networking

One of my co-workers once saw a device that plugged into a RJ45 jack, that emulated a PC.  It could be configured with an IP address, and respond to pings.

I was wondering if anyone knew about these, or even what they are called?

This will be used to simulate a PC in a classroom environment.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: This is a CCNA classroom, we are looking to simulate a PC connected to an ethernet port on a router.  These will be on different subnets, etc.  This might be doable with a VM through VLANs and virtual switches, but then we are getting away from configuring the physical ports on the router the way we want to.

Comment: why not use a VM?

Comment: This is a CCNA classroom, we are looking to simulate a PC connected to an ethernet port on a router.  These will be on different subnets, etc.  This might be doable with a VM through VLANs and virtual switches, but then we are getting away from configuring the physical ports on the router the way we want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe some advanced network testers can do this. ([Example?](http://www.flukenetworks.com/enterprise-network/network-testing/LinkRunner-AT-Network-Auto-Tester), [Example?](http://vonaq.com/LanTesterCableTester.html))

It might be less expensive to plug-in a [rasperry-pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs), [arduino with ethernet-shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) or similar device.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is very close to what I was looking for. It is affordable (The class would need ~24 of them, so cost is a motivating factor). The only two downsides I see to it is it does not have a case (Yes, I know we can get a seperate one), and it does not appear simple to configure (This would require the instructor to prepare all of the devices, and provide instructions on how to change the IP address).    If I don't get a better answer that addresses the case/configuration issues, then I'll approve this one.

Comment: @Mike: Perhaps use a 25th RPi as a DHCP server to hand out IP-addresses. Boot the other 24 from (say) [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) SD cards. Maybe there's a distribution that could run from read-only media?

Comment: Perhaps.  This seems like the best idea I'm gonna get.  The price is really nice.  Thanks!